# RLS Lattice vs Transversal

Tags: filters

I have the RLS algorithm implemented in two different ways - transversal and lattice.

I was expecting them both to behave the same way, but they don't! Transversal seems to converge faster than lattice does. I'm not sure why. I plotted them together here:
[image: Lattice is red, Transversal is blue]

Lattice is shown in red, transversal is in blue. This is MSE.

The lattice is actually a joint process estimator, so I calculate the error.

Is my implementation just wrong and they should be the same, or is this actually supposed to happen? I mean it could probably make sense because reflection coefficients are limited to 1 in magnitude, but I'm not sure.

Furthermore, in the RLS transversal implementation (with the tap weights), the filter response is symmetrical, so I know what the delay of the filter is. But I don't know what the lattice implementation delay would be like, because the regression coefficients do not look symmetrical to me.

Comment: no lattice RLS has large convergence time than the RLS and they both have the same delay.
hope this help